# How can I rename a folder in Lion's Launchpad?

Tags: folders, macos, launchpad

I created a folder by dropping one icon on top of another.

Now I want to rename that folder, since the default name, "Utility" isn't the one I want.

According to all advice I find on the internet, I should open the folder and then *double-click the title* in order to rename it.

But, when I double-click the title, nothing is happening. Is there a lock somewhere I have to turn off?

This is what I tried:

- Double-Clicking
- Right-Clicking
- Ctrl-Clicking
- Option-Clicking
- Command-Clicking

What else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once the folder created (with the name Utility) you click (once) on the folder to open it, 
once opened the name of the folder appears in bold + the different apps inside that folder.

To change the name, click on the name (shown inside the folder) to change it.

Comment: I thought I made that clear in the question - it doesn't work. I've tried that.

Comment: I have lion as well, and i just clicked (not double clicked) and it worked fine. I doubt the made different versions of it.

Comment: There seems to be a bug in this function. See my own answer.

Comment: Just as a point of reference, noktecs solution worked for me with no changes needed after the upgrade from Snow Leopard. Remember, don't double-click the name when opening the folder -- only single click on the name.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, I did a google search and came across a page where others are having the same problem.

The reply by etresoft - https://discussions.apple.com/message/15661045#15661045 - basically says to kill the Dock application and it should restart automatically, and then it should work.

I did that, started Activity Monitor, found Dock, and force-quit it, it started right up again, and afterwards renaming worked as expected.